# textView in QRcode using Zxing

Tags: android

I have this app which consists of three tabs. The first tab has a button to scan QRcode. I didn't use an intent to call the barcode scanner here. I integrated all com.google... into my src. It works smoothly. The issue here, is when I scan for a Qrcode that has a website. The result I get back is the URL itself because of the textView. How do I get this URL to be clickable and redirected to the browser? Or simply show the content of the website in my app. Here is the Result Activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_QRCODE) {
        if (txtQRcodeResult == null) {
            txtQRcodeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }

        txtQRcodeResult.setText(data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to have to click you can use Linkify:

```
Linkify.addLinks(txtQRcodeResult, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

if you want to just jump into the browser and load the page, you can fire an intent:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.VIEW_ACTION,ContentURI.create(data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")));
startActivity(browserIntent );
```

Comment: Thank You Chris, that was really helpful. I actually wasn't aware of Linkify before but now I'm